# Letter ”p” is not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was writing code in an android studio. But recently I am facing a new problem.  My keyboard is okay but letter P is not working in an android studio.
For example, if I write “public” it shows “ublic”, I write “private” it shows “rivate”.
I can easily write in Microsoft word, notepad or all other places.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Which OS you have to use?

Comment: I am using Windows OS. @FenilPatel.

Comment: @MdAbdullahAlMamun Please do this things,

**Go to, File > Invalidate Caches / Restart / Alert dialog appear**

_Click on "Invalidate and Restart" button_

Comment: Cool! it works.Thanks @FenilPatel

Answer (score 0):

May this solution work.

1.clean your project.
2.Rebuild your project.
3.Restart Android Studio.